# Cannot search custom content type in enhanced LWR site

Tags: community, lwr

```
return ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getAllManagedContent(
                communityId,
                pageParam,
                pageSize,
                curLanguage,
                filterby
            );
```

no items returned when i search custom content type

[image]